# How to customize token result format dropdown without starting with <li>

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-tokeninput

**How to customize token result format dropdwon without starting with li tag?**
text1

list1

list1

list1

list1

text2

list2

list2

list2

list2

Answer (score 0):

Use the `resultsFormatter` property.

The default is:

```
function(item){ return "<li>" + item.propertyToSearch + "</li>" }
```

You can change this to whatever you want, e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#my-text-input").tokenInput("/url/to/your/script/", {
        resultsFormatter: function(item) {
            return "<p>" + item.propertyToSearch + "</p>"
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Chris. is it possible to make it as given in the html?

Comment: @MartinJose - Sorry, I don't understand your question? Can you rephrase?